# How "-fstack-protector" and "FORTIFY" option are different?

Tags: linux, gcc

These days I'm searching for the secure coding guide, and there is an option to prevent

the buffer overflow.

one,

```
$gcc -fstack-protector -S test.c
$cat test.s
```

two,

```
$gcc -O -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 test.c
```

I can see the warning of buffer overflow from FORTIFY option but actually I don't have much idea of -fstack-protector option.

Are they completely different and don't have any effect of  prevent the buffer overflow?

Answer (score 0):

-fstack-protector basically creates what is called a canary - dummy variables that are placed in the stack.  On exit of the function, variable is  checked.  If overwritten the program exits with an error message.

_FORTIFY_SOURCE compile time define  is one that checks code for standards violations when optimization is turn on.  So you get an error at compile time rather than at run time like you do with -fstack-protector.

_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 turns on this feature when optimization is set to level 1 or higher.